# Download build and tested assemblies from azure teamcity using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, teamcity

I'm currently running teamcity hosted in azure. I want to find a good solution to get the output of the build on premise aka. download. Thought about using powershell and the Azure SDK, but would like to hear if I should look into other solutions or if this is the way to do it.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One non-PowerShell solution would be to save your outputs as [build artifacts](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Artifact).  You can download these directly from TeamCity over HTTP.

Comment: Hmmm maybe. A combination as I need it in an automated on premise deployment. But I guess I should be able to fetch those files and maybe by som eof the Powershell Azure Cmdlets

Comment: If you don't want to download via HTTP, or require additional authentication, then I would agree that the Powershell Azure Cmdlets are your best choice.